# Setting collection in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a requirement where I have to set collection to the existing documents. The thing is I have around 20 million records. I am running below query from query console. It is throwing time out error.
I also tried out limit=N option in below query. At max I was able to achieve N=40000, after that it's again throwing time out error.
Please help me with any faster query or approach.

`for $each in cts:uri-match("/data/employee/*")
return xdmp:document-set-collections($each, "employee")`

Comment: Creating a CORB batch job would likely be a good solution. https://developer.marklogic.com/code/corb

Comment: Batching up scales better, and is overall faster. There are various ways, including CORB. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52953123/918496 some more..

Answer (score 1):

ml-gradle has OOTB support for this, no code needed. See https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/DMSDK-Tasks#trying-it-out and look at "mlAddCollections".

Comment: Yes, I do remember there is a task with that name. Is there a similar task we can use through roxy framework?

Comment: You could use corb with roxy - easiest approach would be with an ad hoc module. But you can always add a build.gradle file to your Roxy project for the sole purpose of using ml-gradle tasks that aren't related to a deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Batching is the right option to perform this type of task. Use `xdmp:spawn-function()` function to put multiple tasks at a time on the task server. You just need to indentify the number of records which your query can finish within 10 minute or 1 hr as you required.

For example, if query can execute 5000 records within 10 minute:

```
let $total-records := xdmp:estimate(collection())
let $batch-size := 5000
let $pagination := 0
for $records in 1 to fn:ceiling($total-records  div $batch-size )
let $start := fn:sum($pagination + 1)
let $end := fn:sum($batch-size + $pagination)
let $_ := xdmp:set($pagination, $end)
return
  xdmp:spawn-function
  (
  function(),
  for $each in cts:uri-match("/data/employee/*")[$start to $end]
  return xdmp:document-set-collections($each, "employee")
  )
```